# Canceling a celery task from inside itself?

Tags: python, error-handling, celery

I know I could `return`, but I'm wondering if there's something else, especially for helper methods where the task where `return None` would force the caller to add boilerplate checking at each invocation.

I found [InvalidTaskError](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.exceptions.html#celery.exceptions.InvalidTaskError), but no real documentation - is this an internal thing? Is it appropriate to raise this?

I was looking for something like a `self.abort()` similar to the `self.retry()`, but didn't see anything.

Here's an example where I'd use it.

```
def helper(task, arg):
    if unrecoverable_problems(arg):
        # abort the task
        raise InvalidTaskError()

@task(bind=True)
task_a(self, arg):
    helper(task=self, arg=arg)
    do_a(arg)

@task(bind=True)
task_b(self, arg):
    helper(task=self, arg=arg)
    do_b(arg)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After doing more digging, I found an example using [`Reject`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#reject);

(copied from doc page)

> The task may raise Reject to reject the task message using AMQPs basic_reject method. This will not have any effect unless Task.acks_late is enabled.
>
> Rejecting a message has the same effect as acking it, but some brokers may implement additional functionality that can be used. For example RabbitMQ supports the concept of Dead Letter Exchanges where a queue can be configured to use a dead letter exchange that rejected messages are redelivered to.
>
> Reject can also be used to requeue messages, but please be very careful when using this as it can easily result in an infinite message loop.
>
> Example using reject when a task causes an out of memory condition:
>
> ```
> import errno
> from celery.exceptions import Reject
>
> @app.task(bind=True, acks_late=True)
> def render_scene(self, path):
>     file = get_file(path)
>     try:
>         renderer.render_scene(file)
>
>     # if the file is too big to fit in memory
>     # we reject it so that it's redelivered to the dead letter exchange
>     # and we can manually inspect the situation.
>     except MemoryError as exc:
>         raise Reject(exc, requeue=False)
>     except OSError as exc:
>         if exc.errno == errno.ENOMEM:
>             raise Reject(exc, requeue=False)
>
>     # For any other error we retry after 10 seconds.
>     except Exception as exc:
>         raise self.retry(exc, countdown=10)
> ```