# Is there a pattern for gracefully shutting down celery task Pods in Kubernetes?

Tags: python, kubernetes, celery

I'm tackling the graceful roll-out of software changes to Pods running Celery tasks. I currently run one or more celery worker containers in their own Pods and need to ensure that they are safely (gracefully) shutdown prior to starting a new container image.

Existing tasks in the Pod need to be allowed to finish, but I don't want to start any new tasks.

I'm using the Kubernetes Deployments's `RollingUpdate` update strategy along with a `lifecycle->preStop` **hook**. The hook allows me to delay the removal of the Pod by adding a script into the container that Kubernetes will allow to block until it's safe to remove the Pod. The underlying hook logic is not the issue, my concern is ... knowing that Kubernetes wants to stop the Pod ... how do I *neatly* prevent any new tasks in the Pod from running?

So I use my **lifecycle hook** to modify the container state so the container knows it should "finish what it's doing but not to start anything new". When all the tasks have "drained" I can then allow kubernetes to delete the Pod (bu returning from my hook).

I suspect I should use the `Reject()` exception as suggested in "[Canceling a celery task from inside itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346409)".

But ... if I have a large number of disparate tasks I want to avoid having to introduce conditional `Reject` logic in every task implementation, i.e. I don't want to introduce this in every task...

```
if poisoned():
    _LOGGER.warning("Pod has been poisoned!")
    raise Reject(reason="Poisoned", requeue=True)
```

Is there a neat class-based/inheritance solution I can employ?

For example, could I put the above into the `before_start()` celery task method, and have that method reject (and re-queue) the task before it starts?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Celery, but apparently the management tool [flower](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) provides a method for telling a worker to [stop consuming events from a queue](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#post--api-worker-queue-cancel-consumer-(.+)), which is pretty much what you're asking for.

Comment: A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73235267/5045925) and there seems to be an answer that explains that celery already handles what you need, and you just need to make sure K8s is configured not the send a SIGKILL too soon after SIGTERM.